# multiple Django projects in one directory

Tags: python, django

Iam trying to create multiple projects into one existing django project.
The directory should be set up as follows

[directory picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYKIe.jpg)

Is it possible to use this direcory without using multiple databases and config files. Everything in a single django instance?
If so, how?

The problem is, i cant reach the moduls in my mainproject urls.py. They cant be found.

thanks :)

Comment: I think you must put a __init__.py in your mainproject root's folder

Comment: It doesn't work @FernandoFreitasAlves

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do this? If you need two different django projects, keep them as different django projects.

It is different if you want to use the same database and reuse some of your existing apps.

For the first, you can set that in your settings.py file of each project to point to a common database, you can even manage to share only some tables in a common database and keep the others as a separated database for each project (there are some limitations with that approach though). Check [django multidb docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) for more info.

For the second, you can create a folder containing your django apps (with their models definitions, views, admin and whatever you need) and import them in the settings.py. An example:

```
APPS_PATH = "/django/apps/folder/"
sys.path.insert(0, APPS_PATH)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
...

custom_app1,
custom_app2,
)
```

You may also want to check [django sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).

Hope it helps.